# How to remove the border of a Tkinter OptionMenu Widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, colors, optionmenu

I have been looking through multiple websites, which only give me a half satisfactory answer, how would I colour each part of of a Tkinter OptionMenu Widget?

Code Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
text = StringVar()

fr = Frame (root,bg="yellow")
fr.grid()

menu = OptionMenu (fr, text, "hi", "there")
menu.grid (pady=50, padx=50)

# Pretty colouring goes here
# Or ugly yellow, I don't mind

menu ["menu"] ["bg"] = "yellow"
menu ["bg"] = "yellow"
menu ["activebackground"] = "green"

root.mainloop()
```

Or should I just give up and settle for grey?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All that I had to do was set the `highlightthickness` option to `0`

`menu["highlightthickness"]=0`

This get's rid of the ugly border around the drop down menu.

Answer (score 1):

to get rid of the border use the option : menu["borderwidth"] = 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem.

menu["menu"] is a tkinter.Menu object, so you can set others options.

Possible colors options are :

- activebackground -> that you want
- activeforeground -> that you want
- background
- bg
- disabledforeground
- fg
- foreground
- selectcolor

Comment: Issue is this leaves a border of grey around the outside of the OptionMenu, and I want to change the colour of that.